# Place existing XAML vector graphics in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, coordinates

I want to make a product configurator. I want to display the product in the main window with xaml vector graphics and then export a dxf file (as technical drawing.) The dxf export already works.

The main part of the product is drawed with lines, no problem here (drawed as a rectangle). But other installations are more complex, for example a 230V-outlet. The outlet is static, so I don't need to draw it with code. I created a outlet.xaml file with Inkscape. How can I place that xaml-file on a specific place (coordinates) in my canvas?

In dxf it was very easy - I created a block as external dxf file, and i could insert it in the drawing like this:

```
DxfDocument doc = new DxfDocument();
doc.DrawingVariables.InsUnits = DrawingUnits.Millimeters;

//Insert existing DXF
netDxf.Blocks.Block Steckdose = netDxf.Blocks.Block.Load("Steckdose.dxf");
Insert i = new Insert(Steckdose, new Vector2(200,200));
doc.AddEntity(i);           
doc.Save("test.dxf");
```

Is there any way to do that with xaml? Please notice: the number and position of the outlets should be variable, so I wanted to draw them with c# code.

For testing, I made a window with two textboxes: one for the with of the rectangle, one for the x coordinate of the outlet.
Thats my code so far:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int value1;
    int value2;   
    if (int.TryParse(txt_laenge.Text, out value1) & int.TryParse(txt_laenge.Text, out value2))
    {
        Länge = value1;
        int SD = value2;
        var rechteck = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        rechteck.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rechteck.Height = 136;
        rechteck.Width = Länge;
        Canvas.SetLeft(rechteck,0);
        Canvas.SetTop(rechteck, 0);
        IV.Children.Clear();
        IV.Children.Add(rechteck);
        //Place Steckdose.xaml at coordinates (SD, 68);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ungültige Eingabe!");
    }
}
```

Edit: The Steckdose(outlet).xaml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is NOT compatible with Silverlight-->
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Name="svg8" Width="44" Height="44">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
    <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
    <Canvas Name="layer1">
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-253"/>
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="0.13150091" Canvas.Top="253.1315" Width="43.737" Height="43.737" RadiusX="4.4731021" RadiusY="4.4731021" Name="rect3680" Fill="#FF008000" StrokeThickness="0.26300183" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
      <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="2.7" Width="38.6" Canvas.Top="255.7" Height="38.6" Name="path4487" Fill="#FF008000" StrokeThickness="0.35593221" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
      <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="9.7" Width="4.6" Canvas.Top="272.7" Height="4.6" Name="path4491" Fill="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="0.36692113" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
      <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="29.7" Width="4.6" Canvas.Top="272.7" Height="4.6" Name="path44915" Fill="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="0.36692113" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Depends on the exact object type contained in outlet.xaml. You may use `XamlReader.Load()` to load the XAML, and cast the return value to the appropriate type. Then add the loaded object to your Canvas.

Comment: Can't you create a UserControl and use the generated Xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UIElement element;

using (var stream = new FileStream("Outlet.xaml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    element = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(stream);
}

Canvas.SetLeft(element, 100);
Canvas.SetLeft(element, 50);
canvas.Children.Add(element);
```